Is this a proper generalization of Sheaf or an alternative definition of one? Open covers in the second axiom are $\pi$-systems (closed under $\cap$)
Let $F : O(X)^{\text{op}} \to \text{CommRing}$ be a ring-valued sheaf of continuous functions, where (at least in my application) $F(U) = \{ U \to A \text{ continuous}\}$ where $A$ is a fixed topological ring throughout.
We keep the same first axiom of Sheaf (uniqueness).
Modify the second axiom to be:


(Gluing) Suppose that $U$ is an open set and $C = \{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $U$ ($U_i \subset U, \forall i$), but further suppose that $C$ is a $\pi$-system.  In other words, suppose that $C$ is closed under finite intersections.   Let $S = \{ s_i \in F(U_i)\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of sections.  If all pairs of sections agree on the overlap of their domains, i.e. $\forall i,j; s_i|_{U_i \cap U_j} = s_j|_{U_i \cap U_j}$, then there exists a section $s \in F(U)$ such that $s|_{U_i} = s_i, \ \forall i$.


Clearly this is a generalization of Sheaf since for every Sheaf $F$ we have that axiom 2 works with general families of open sets, so it certainly works for the subclass of families which are $\pi$-systems.  (This is a little fuzzy for me, but hopefully I got that correct).
Was wondering, intuitively it seems like a $\pi$-system Sheaf, as defined above, is the same thing as a Sheaf.  But I don't quite see how to prove it.  Is it a proper generalization or an equivalent definition?

Will be adding an attempt after I think about it some more.

I feel like this should be equivalent to the usual condition, I'm not sure though

I’ll take it either way.  I think  I can adapt my problem to whatever the answer to this is

Almost.
Notice that a $\pi$-system is defined as a non-empty set of subsets which is closed under binary intersection. This means that it is non-empty and closed under non-empty finite intersections (meaning the indexing set is not empty). Recall that the empty intersection is always the ambient set. We do not demand this here.
Assume that the sheaf property holds for $\pi$-systems and the empty family. Take any open cover and compatible sections. Consider the finite non-empty intersections of all sets in the cover. This is still an open cover, and it is a $\pi$-system or empty (namely, when the original cover was empty). Also, we may shrink down all our sections to the intersections. They are still compatible. Hence they glue. Since every set in the original cover is also part of the refined cover, by treating it as an intersection of length $1$, we are done.
Now consider the empty topological space. A presheaf of, say, rings on it is just equivalent to a ring, since we can map the empty set to anything we want. The only $\pi$-system is here $\{\emptyset\}$. For this, the sheaf property is satisfied. In fact, the sheaf property always holds for covers which have just one set inside. But the sheaf property, which also includes the empty cover $\emptyset$, demands that $R$ is the trivial ring. This is what we are missing out if we only take $\pi$-systems.
Similarly, for any space, the value of the sheaf at the empty set can just be the trivial ring (more generally, the terminal object in the target category we choose for our sheaves), and you cannot prove this with non-empty covers alone. You might not care about the empty set, but it is crucial to define basic properties and to keep the theory consistent. An example is the property that a section on a disjoint union of two open subsets is always given by a pair of sections on the two open subsets. You won't be able to prove this when you only require the sheaf axiom for non-empty sets.
Related MO thread

What is a non-empty topology? Also, have you read the last paragraph?

I think I what I want then based on your last paragraph is sheave axioms for non empty intersections of elements in the open covers.  Do these have a name?

Why do you ask me what a non empty topology is when you gave me the example of an empty one?

A topology is never empty. Please read more carefully.

I guess what I meant is to rule out that case my space is definitely not empty, so will this work if I also axiomatize the “sheaf” to be for non empty intersections as well?  In other words every sheaf (for any overlaps including empty) is a “sheaf” (sections  only necessarily compatible for non empty overlaps)

No, please don't do that, I have answered this in the last paragraph.

Your last paragraph merely gives two real world examples that would break, but I currently have not ties to these examples in my current application.  So is the answer yes and no?

I don’t really need all of sheaf theory to work out ️ it’s just that I would like to use the definition or similar of a “sheaf” because I have some sections that live in one that I’d like to prove have an associated global section.  And that’s the extent to which I’m using sheaves currently.  So now can I do that?  That is I want to prove that the global section is continuous
